# nodejs event loop and sleep

Tags: node.js, multithreading

i have a question about the sleep function in nodejs and the events loop :

[image]

We can see from this image that io operation are delegate to posix thread, so if i call sleep inside my nodejs code, the io operation will remain working, and when the sleep is over, the nodejs loop will find the buffer of io operation full of data.

Is that correct?

edit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep

Comment: What is *the sleep function*??

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep

Comment: It says on the NPM page, in bold **These calls will block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js' event loop!** - Except for debugging, why would you ever want to suspend the event loop?

Comment: i will not, just asking to understand how everything work :)